# Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, identity, acl

I try to give full access to normal users by using this script. This PowerShell script is perfectly working in My machine. But it is not working in Other machines. Below mentioned powershell script.

```
$key = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Unicorn",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck]::ReadWriteSubTree,[System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights]::ChangePermissions)
$acl = $key.GetAccessControl()
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule (".\USERS","FullControl",@("ObjectInherit","ContainerInherit"),"None","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
$key.SetAccessControl($acl)

Write-Host "Successfully set permission to PM Registry!"
```

Here I attached error message also.

[image: error message]

Comment: Sounds like it cannot resolve name `.\Users`. Is this by any chance a localized version of Windows? This group name may be localized as well.

Comment: @raspy How I replace it as common compatible with other machines???

Comment: In my case, getting rid of the ".\" in front of ".\USERS" did the trick.

Comment: @ShawnEary How I overcome this issue with many machine with different user name???

Comment: Sorry my comment didn't help.  I was drawn to your post because it helped me solve a similar problem I was having.  I just got rid of ".\" and the annoying error went away.  If you have different domains and machines, then maybe something like this would work:
RegistryAccessRule ("SHORT_NAME_OF_HOST_COMPUTER\USER","FullControl", ...).  So if you had computers named Maple and Birch with example.com (i.e. Maple.example.com and Birch.example.com) then maybe you would use commands like: RegistryAccessRule ("Maple\doej","FullControl", ...) and RegistryAccessRule ("Birch\brownl","FullControl", ...)